# It there a way to leave a function argument undeclared

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

I am looking for a way to declare a function without declaring one or more parameters.  This would be used in cases where you're implementing a function where you don't care what the value of (for instance) the first argument is.

For example, given this function:

```
function foo(this_arg_is_unused, important_arg) {
    doSomethingWith(important_arg);
}
```

Is there some way to declare it more like this?

```
function foo( , important_arg) {
    doSomethingWith(important_arg);
}
```

I realize I could easily do this:

```
function foo() {
    doSomethingWith(arguments[1]);
}
```

However that starts becoming less readable and it would be more difficult to (for instance) use fn.js to curry the arguments.

I'm currently thinking perhaps I could just use a visual mnemonic to indicate the argument is not used:

```
function foo(ø, important_arg) {
    doSomethingWith(important_arg);
}
```

However this may also have readability issues.

Real world example:

The callback function used by [jQuery's .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) takes two arguments, the first is either the index or property name in the array/object and the second is the value.  To manipulate some `div` elements you might do something like this:

```js
$($('div').each(function(index, value) {
        console.log(value); // equivalent to doSomething(this)
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Nothing here</div>
```

Using an arrow function (where using arguments[] is not possible)

```js
$($('div').each((ø, value) => console.log(value)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Nothing here</div>
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript has any language support for that. A Haskell convention is to use a name that starts with an underscore (e.g. `_index`).

Comment: @joews Did you not look at the real world example?  Quite often.  Most people don't even bother to give the callback for `.each()` arguments since `this` is handy - but you can't use `this` in an arrow function

Comment: I always use `_` for the don't care arguments.

Comment: ...and you can do like `function x(...a){ carryOnWith(...a.slice(1)) }`

Comment: @Redu `_` would have been my first pick too, except there's at least a couple of libraries that are using it (underscore, gettext) and I'd like to avoid potential issues

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave empty spaces in function arguments. A placeholder argument works well.

If you don't want to do that, you could write a higher-order function that wraps a function to expect a first, throwaway argument:

```
function withExtraArg(f, thisValue = null) {
  return (x, ...args) => f.call(thisValue, ...args);
}
```

And write your function taking a natural number of arguments:

```js
function withExtraArg(f, thisValue = null) {
  return (x, ...args) => f.call(thisValue, ...args);
}

// your function
function log (value) {
  console.log(value)
}

$($('div').each(withExtraArg(log)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Nothing here</div>
```

Comment: `f.call(args)` looks wrong. Did you mean `f(...args)`? And that would neglect the `this` value.

Comment: Fixed as you were commenting :-)

Comment: Still not working, it needs to be `f.call(thisArg, ...args)` or `f.apply(thisArg, args)`

Answer (score 0):

> It there a way to leave a function argument undeclared?

No. Just omitting it is a syntax error.

> Perhaps I could just use a visual mnemonic to indicate the argument is not used

Yes, that's the right way. The idiomatic name for unused parameters is the underscore `_`, known from other languages where it has a special meaning (and can even be used multiple times):

```
function foo(_, important_arg) {
```

> Real world example: the callback function used by jQuery's `.each()`

Yes, jQuery has messed up the arguments order of the callback, usually the value goes first. In jQuery, the value goes in the zeroeth argument - the `this` value, so idiomatic jQuery is

```
$('div').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

If you cannot use `this` for some reason, you will have to use the second parameter; there's no way around this.

Comment: I'd like to use `_`, but it would break gettext (which is why I'm leaning towards using the "null").  I'm aware of the jQuery idiom, but it fails in arrow functions.

Comment: @Tibrogargan What do you mean by "gettext"? And yes, [you're not supposed to use arrow functions everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) - jQuery could be considered broken in that regard, but they'll hardly change it for compatibility reasons (as always in JS).

Comment: [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).  There's libraries for it in many languages and many of them (including JS) use `_` as their macro/global/hook

Comment: I guess using two underscores (`__`) would work as well if you need to avoid collisions. Or just name it `index` and simply not use it.

Comment: either that or use joews answer (which is functionally the same as fn.js:curry()).  I'm thinking maybe the [Haskell style] __ / _xyz / _unused  might be the easiest, but maybe I'll stick with my ø

Comment: @Tibrogargan isn't it more like the inverse of partial application? In that it effectively increases the arity of a function.

Comment: @joews You're right.  I shouldn't assume people are telepathic :)  functionally the same family. It modifies the arity.

Comment: @bergi I really want to just plonk `void` in there in place of any argument I'm not using.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yeah, unfortunately `void` is a keyword…

Comment: @joews what you've written is basically the `const` function (if we assume curried functions)

Comment: @Bergi that's neat, thanks. I [read about that recently](https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read) but didn't make the connection.